# Powershell: Can't post to Slack with otherwise working script

Tags: windows-10, script, powershell, slack

I am totally new to Powershell, but I needed an all-Windows solution for a Slack bot that monitors local folders.

I am able to use the CLI to post to Slack successfully with the following two commands:

```
$postSlackMessage = @{token="";channel="#general";text="Test message";username="Bot User"}

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage -Body $postSlackMessage
```

I am also able to monitor the folder using the script provided on [this superuser answer](https://superuser.com/a/844034/329107) by @nixda.

My version of this great solution doesn't seem to cut it. Here it is:

```
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = "C:\Location\"
    $watcher.Filter = "*.*"
    $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER A EVENT IS DETECTED
    $action = { $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
                $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
                $token = ""
                $channel = "$general"
                $text = "$changeType, $path"
                $username = "Bot User"
                $postSlackMessage = @{token=$token; channel=$channel; text=$text; username=$username}
                Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage -Body $postSlackMessage
              }    
### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED + SET CHECK FREQUENCY  
    $created = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
    $changed = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
    $deleted = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action $action
    $renamed = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action
    while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

I've tried a number of different variations on this and I am not sure what I'm doing wrong. I can get the nixda script to work and write to a txt file but changing the action to Invoke-RestMethod doesn't work.

Is this a syntax problem I'm not getting, or something greater I'm missing?

Comment: Does it produce an error when it "doesn't work" with Invoke-RestMethod? Is $postSlackMessage populated as expected when you get to that line during execution?

Comment: This is an excellent question, nothing seems to come up in the PS window running it and I don't have any experience using Try Catch. If you have a reference or advice I'll update the script and share the error.

Comment: Off hand I see `$channel = "$general"` appears to be wrong.  You haven't defined `$general` anywhere, and in your "working" example, it's `"#general"`.

Comment: Use an editor that allows breakpoint: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/ise/how-to-debug-scripts-in-windows-powershell-ise

Comment: Yes, that's a bit of ignorance I caught and thought I fixed. It's supposed to be slack channel #general. I'll update that.

Comment: Re: breakpoint I have a lot to learn. I'll digest what's on that page and see what I can update. Thank you for this advice.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 That syntax error actually fixed the problem if you'd like to post it as an answer. The script works as expected with the channel listed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are a few views on this I'll post the corrected script, as pointed out by Techie007. It was only a minor typo and this posts to Slack if you'd like use Powershell scripts to watch folders in Windows:

```
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = "C:\Location\"
    $watcher.Filter = "*.*"
    $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER A EVENT IS DETECTED
    $action = { $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
                $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
                $token = ""
                $channel = "#general"
                $text = "$changeType, $path"
                $username = "Bot User"
                $postSlackMessage = @{token=$token; channel=$channel; text=$text; username=$username}
                Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage -Body $postSlackMessage
              }    
### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED + SET CHECK FREQUENCY  
    $created = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
    $changed = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
    $deleted = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action $action
    $renamed = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action
    while ($true) {sleep 5}
```