# Use PowerShell & System.IO.FileSystemWatcher to detect when a download to a specific folder is complete

Tags: google-chrome, powershell, automation, scheduled-tasks, download-manager

I'm attempting to monitor my download folder and trigger a command-line action when a download is completed. This is very similar to another question, [How to monitor a folder and trigger a command-line action when a file is created or edited?](https://superuser.com/questions/226828/how-to-monitor-a-folder-and-trigger-a-command-line-action-when-a-file-is-created)

I've implemented the PowerShell script described in the [most upvoted answer](https://superuser.com/a/844034/980258), but when I run it, I'm finding that the output is confusing.

```
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = "Z:\UnprocessedDownloads"
    $watcher.Filter = "*.*"
    $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
    $action = { $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
                $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
                $logline = "$(Get-Date -f o), $changeType, $path"
                Add-content "Z:\log.txt" -value $logline
              }    
### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action $action
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action
    while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

I should note that the downloads in question are being created by Chrome, which may or may not explain what's going on. As best I can tell, the series of events is as follows:

1. A file with the intended filename is created.
2. The previously created file is promptly deleted.
3. A file with the intended filename, and **.crdownload** appended, is created.
4. This file registers between two and three changes (of the files I tested, if it was a few KB it showed two, but files 100MB to 10GB registered three).
5. This file is renamed, removing the **.crdownload**.
6. This file then registers an additional two to three changes (I couldn't find any rhyme or reason to how many occurred).
7. It's done, nothing else registers without manual intervention.

So, that's that. I'm at a loss as to how I can tell a file is truly "done", short of perhaps watching for a rename event, and subsequently waiting for an arbitrary number of seconds (occasionally, the last recorded change took about 5 seconds to occur - I just realized this is likely due to the sleep 5 in the script), perhaps 10.

Can anyone explain what's going on here? Are there any suggestions or alternatives? I'm not beholden to PowerShell, it just seemed like it and the File System Watcher would be well suited to the task. I'd prefer something with as little overhead as possible while retaining automation.

FWIW, an excerpt from my tests (hardly extensive; note - I did adjust the log to show milliseconds):

```
2019-01-02T22:03:03.6712039-05:00, Created, Z:\Unprocessed\test (1).jpg
2019-01-02T22:03:03.7242040-05:00, Deleted, Z:\Unprocessed\test (1).jpg
2019-01-02T22:03:03.7252054-05:00, Created, Z:\Unprocessed\test (1).jpg.crdownload
2019-01-02T22:03:03.7252054-05:00, Changed, Z:\Unprocessed\test (1).jpg.crdownload
2019-01-02T22:03:08.7265875-05:00, Changed, Z:\Unprocessed\test (1).jpg.crdownload
2019-01-02T22:03:08.7305994-05:00, Renamed, Z:\Unprocessed\test (1).jpg
2019-01-02T22:03:08.7315887-05:00, Changed, Z:\Unprocessed\test (1).jpg
2019-01-02T22:03:08.7315887-05:00, Changed, Z:\Unprocessed\test (1).jpg
2019-01-02T22:03:13.7348367-05:00, Changed, Z:\Unprocessed\test (1).jpg
2019-01-02T22:09:28.7729475-05:00, Deleted, Z:\Unprocessed\10GB.bin
2019-01-02T22:09:33.7742846-05:00, Created, Z:\Unprocessed\1GB.bin
2019-01-02T22:09:33.7762852-05:00, Deleted, Z:\Unprocessed\1GB.bin
2019-01-02T22:09:33.7772866-05:00, Created, Z:\Unprocessed\1GB.bin.crdownload
2019-01-02T22:09:33.7782853-05:00, Changed, Z:\Unprocessed\1GB.bin.crdownload
2019-01-02T22:09:33.7792825-05:00, Changed, Z:\Unprocessed\1GB.bin.crdownload
2019-01-02T22:10:28.7850646-05:00, Changed, Z:\Unprocessed\1GB.bin.crdownload
2019-01-02T22:10:28.7860648-05:00, Renamed, Z:\Unprocessed\1GB.bin
2019-01-02T22:10:28.7870652-05:00, Changed, Z:\Unprocessed\1GB.bin
2019-01-02T22:10:28.7870652-05:00, Changed, Z:\Unprocessed\1GB.bin
2019-01-02T22:10:28.7880654-05:00, Changed, Z:\Unprocessed\1GB.bin
2019-01-02T22:11:13.7928495-05:00, Created, Z:\Unprocessed\test (2).jpg
2019-01-02T22:11:13.7938482-05:00, Deleted, Z:\Unprocessed\test (2).jpg
2019-01-02T22:11:13.7938482-05:00, Created, Z:\Unprocessed\test (2).jpg.crdownload
2019-01-02T22:11:13.7948490-05:00, Changed, Z:\Unprocessed\test (2).jpg.crdownload
2019-01-02T22:11:18.7972830-05:00, Changed, Z:\Unprocessed\test (2).jpg.crdownload
2019-01-02T22:11:18.7982945-05:00, Renamed, Z:\Unprocessed\test (2).jpg
2019-01-02T22:11:18.7992839-05:00, Changed, Z:\Unprocessed\test (2).jpg
2019-01-02T22:11:18.8002947-05:00, Changed, Z:\Unprocessed\test (2).jpg
2019-01-02T22:11:23.8011169-05:00, Changed, Z:\Unprocessed\test (2).jpg
```

Comment: This code notwithstanding, when a file download should only be one of course, but as a download is executing, a stub is created until it is done, just like a .tmp file is created when you open Word and doe into go away until you save and close Word. If you think the other things are a side affect of Chrome (which means you have Chrome as your default), then try another browser by setting it as the default. This sounds to me like something is affecting the download and you are getting start overs, thus the extra files.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; I realized the .crdownload was a temporary file stud. There aren't any extra files, just extra changes. I'm baffled by the "false file" at the start, and then all the changes after the rename, I'd expect the rename to be the last step.

Comment: I'd expect rename if needed after the file download was complete, or named before the download begins. It makes little sense to rename part way thru.  See the other options I've suggested to try to see if they are better for you.

Comment: I'd expect the rename on completion as well, that's why I'm confused by the ongoing changes afterwards. Why/what is changing at that point? And I'd be less confused if the originally created file, with the final filename, was renamed to append **.crdownload**, but deleting it and creating a new file makes no sense to me!

Answer (score 2):

Give this a shot. I modified the original to include additional logic. Not sure how bullet proof this will be. Let me know how it holds up.

```
# create an array that tracks each file
$global:files = @()
# where we will move the file once it is free
$destination = "C:\destination"

$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "C:\source"
$watcher.Filter = "*.*"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

$action = {
    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $logline = "$(Get-Date -f o), $changeType, $path"
    Add-content "C:\log.txt" -value $logline
    Write-Host $logline

    if($changeType -eq "Renamed" -and $path.Split(".")[-1] -ne "crdownload") {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Found the file we need! $path"
        Add-content "C:\log.txt" -value "Found the file we need! $path"
        $global:files += $path
    }
}    

Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action $action
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action

while ($true) {

    # if there are any files to process, check if they are locked
    if($global:files) {

        $global:files | % {

            $file = $_
            # assume the file is locked
            $fileFree = $false

            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Checking if the file is locked... ($file)"
            Add-content "C:\log.txt" -value "Checking if the file is locked... ($_)"

            # true  = file is free
            # false = file is locked
            try {
                [IO.File]::OpenWrite($file).close();Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "File is free! ($file)"
                Add-content "C:\log.txt" -value "File is free! ($file)"
                $fileFree = $true
            }
            catch {
                Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "File is Locked ($file)"
                Add-content "C:\log.txt" -value "File is Locked ($file)"
            }

            if($fileFree) {

                # do what we want with the file, since it is free
                Move-Item $file $destination
                Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Moving file ($file)"
                Add-content "C:\log.txt" -value "Moving file ($file)"

                # make sure we don't progress until the file has finished moving
                while(Test-Path $file) {
                    Sleep 1
                }

                # remove the current file from the array
                Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Done processing this file. ($file)"
                Add-content "C:\log.txt" -value "Done processing this file. ($file)"
                $global:files = $global:files | ? { $_ -ne $file }
            }

        }
    }

    sleep 2
}
```

- This will listen for a `Renamed` event where the file extension is not "crdownload", helping us get the actual path/file/extension and not the temporary file's information. When a match is found, it is stored in an array, allowing us to work with multiple files at once.
- Once the array contains one or more file names, each file is checked to see if it is currently locked or if it is free. If it is free, it is moved to `$destination`. You can change the desired action from a `Move-Item` to whatever you'd like.
- Once a file has moved successfully, it is removed from the array.

Know that the multiple `Changed` events you are seeing are to be [expected](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.7.2) (and also occur for me when downloading from Chrome):

> Common file system operations might raise more than one event. For
>   example, when a file is moved from one directory to another, several
>   OnChanged and some OnCreated and OnDeleted events might be raised.
>   Moving a file is a complex operation that consists of multiple simple
>   operations, therefore raising multiple events. Likewise, some
>   applications (for example, antivirus software) might cause additional
>   file system events that are detected by FileSystemWatcher.

You may want to remove the added `Write-Host` lines. You may also want to add the following in a termination catch to gracefully terminate the registered events:

```
Get-EventSubscriber | ? { $_.EventName -in "Created","Changed","Deleted","Renamed" } | Unregister-Event
```

[Inspiration](https://www.codeproject.com/Answers/400321/Problem-in-filesystemwatcher#answer2).

[Checking if a file is locked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24994480/2844212).

Comment: Thanks for this! I especially appreciate the excerpt about how _common file system operations might raise more than one event_ as I'd suspected everything was technically "expected", but seeing the documentation about it is definitely reassuring. I'd even been speculating that my anti-virus software might have been responsible for the occasionally lagging "Changed" event. While I've got a workable solution in place, this looks like it might be more elegant, along with handling multiple files, so I'll attempt to adjust it to my needs accordingly and get back to you (and give credit).