# Tail a file for changes and run a script when a change is detected

Tags: windows-10, powershell, batch, script

I need a way to track updates/modifications to a file in real time and run a batch script when they take place, I have tried [this](https://superuser.com/questions/226828/how-to-monitor-a-folder-and-trigger-a-command-line-action-when-a-file-is-created) to no avail, which may be due to it being open in the program that is logging output to the file, but

> Get-content filename -Tail 0 -Wait

in powershell will show me any updates that happen to the file, is there any way for me to make it launch a script when a change is detected or any other way to do so. I need it to be in either batch or powershell script.
Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Why did you post this twice: ---https://superuser.com/questions/1544741/tail-a-file-for-changes-and-run-a-script-when-a-change-is-detected

Comment: this is the 3rd minor variant of this question you have asked [and that i have found]. **_PLEASE do not spam the site!_** [*frown*]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *tail* why not just periodically do this first batch file:

```
REM 60 second looping check on TARGETFILE for a change of that file
:TOP
copy dir-out dir-out.old  
if errorlevel = 2 dir TARGETFILE > dir-out.old
dir TARGETFILE > dir-out  
fc dir-out dir-out.old 
if errorlevel = 1 goto:EOF
sleep 60s
goto:TOP
:EOF 
NAMEOFSECONDBATCHFILE.BAT
```

Step 1: *copy dir-out dir-out.old* uses the [copy](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html) command which is a part of Windows to make a copy of the old copy of the directory listing. If there is no file **dir-out** then you will get an errorlevel value of 2; more on that later.

Step 2: if *errorlevel = 2 dir TARGETFILE > dir-out.old*

The first time you run this script, there won't be a file named **dir-out.old*, so we make one to prime the pump and keep the script from breaking.   [errorlevel](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html) is also a part of Windows.

Step 3: *dir TARGETFILE > dir-out* uses the [dir](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) command which is a part of Windows to get a directory listing about **TARGETFILE** which is the file you want to watch; replace **TARGETFILE** with the name of the file you wish to track

Step 4: *fc dir-out dir-out.old* uses the [fc](https://ss64.com/nt/fc.html) command which is a part of Windows to compare the directory listing you just made 'dir-out', to the previous version of that directory listing 'dir-out.old'. If they're the same, the value of the variable errorlevel = 0. If they're not the same, the value of the variable errorlevel changes to 1.

Step 5: *if errorlevel = 1 goto:EOF* when a change is detected go to the end of this batch file to launch your second script *SECONDBATHFILE.BAT*

Step 6:  *sleep 60s* relies on a free, open source utility [sleep](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sleep-invocation.html#sleep-invocation) which you get from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm Windows does not have a utility to wait for a specific time, so we get a reliable utility and add it into c:\Windows\System32 or somewhere else in your path. The value 60 here is arbitrary and you can change that to whatever you want.

Step 7: OK, you've slept; time to check again. Go back to the top of the loop.

Step 8: EOF is a marker. You only go here when a change in TARGETFILE is found.

Step 9: NAMEOFSECONDBATCHFILE.BAT is also named arbitrarily and you can change it to whatever you want. That's the name of the batch file to do whatever you want done when a file change is detected.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really sure what you mean by this, could you please clarify? What are dir-out and the targetfile supposed to be