# Run a script when a file is modified

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, batch, script

I need a way to track updates/modifications to a file in real time and run a batch script when they take place, I have tried [this](https://superuser.com/questions/226828/how-to-monitor-a-folder-and-trigger-a-command-line-action-when-a-file-is-created) to no avail, which may be due to it being open in the program that is logging output to the file, but

> Get-content filename -Tail 0 -Wait

in powershell will show me any updates that happen to the file, is there any way for me to make it launch a script when a change is detected or any other way to do so. I need it to be in either batch or powershell script.

Comment: In *nix I'd use the stat command to look at the last modified time via stat - according to this you can do that in batch/powershell:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520643/windows-batch-file-check-if-file-has-been-modified

Answer (score 0):

Use a file system watcher and take action on the event.

> Powershell FileSystemWatcher
>
> https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b
>
> This script uses the .net FileSystemWatcher class to subscribe to
>   'create', 'change' and 'delete' events on files or folders in the NTFS
>   filesystem.It can be used to monitor a folder or folders, and can be
>   modified to perform any action upon the triggering of these events.
>
> Download:  FileSystemWatcher.ps1
>
> https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b/file/42206/1/FileSystemWatcher.ps1

Comment: I've tried that already

Comment: @user1166618 - so ... what did not work as you expected AND exactly what code did you use? "I've tried that already" is nearly useless ... you need to add what you did & what failed to work as expected.