# How to automatically set up a series of reminders whenever a new file is created in a folder?

Tags: terminal, windows-11, scheduled-tasks, monitoring, reminder

I want to do that on a Win11 machine. Let's say folder A has sub-folders B, C... Whenever a new file of a .xyz extension is created in any of them (but not when modified), a series of 6 reminders is created and linked to that file, at a specific time on days D+2, +6, 14, 30, 62 and 126; each with a simple message scheme. For example, the D+2 reminder is always "Review filename.xyz!" at 1.15PM, the D+30 "Summarize filename!" at 1.25PM, etc. When a reminder is due, it will check if the file is still there (I don't know how to deal in case of the file being renamed, please enlighten me): if not, it'll do nothing; if yes, it'll play a chosen sound file and even wake the device if needed. There is a "snooze" button for 8 minutes and no "stop" button - the reminder can only be turned off when that linked file is opened.

I guess this needs some sort of monitoring function and task doing. After perusing Task Scheduler's trigger system, I came to the conclusion that as a practically non-programmer, I can't do it. Searching online gave me pretty much [similar situation](https://superuser.com/questions/226828/how-to-monitor-a-folder-and-trigger-a-command-line-action-when-a-file-is-created)s. Could you help? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps consider using the File Audit function:   ......   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/apply-a-basic-audit-policy-on-a-file-or-folder

Comment: Perhaps there's some existing app to do this... if you're not comfortable programming, you'd need to find one. Try asking at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/