# FileSystemWatcher does not react to changes in excel file

Tags: windows, windows-10, filesystems, automation

I am trying to create a systemFileWatcher that watches a specific excel file for any changes. When triggered it should runs a few commands, logs the activity and then continues watching. However, for now I am unable to get the watcher to react to changes in the .xlsx file. My watcher is currently set up as follows, based an [answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/226828/how-to-monitor-a-folder-and-trigger-a-command-line-action-when-a-file-is-created).

```
$watch_path = 'D:\Projects\test\'
$watch_file = 'test.xlsx'

### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = $watch_path
    $watcher.Filter = $watch_file
    $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
    $action = { $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
                $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
                $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path"
                Add-content "log.txt" -value $logline
              }    
### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
    while ($true) {sleep 60}
```

This does not trigger on a save within the excel program, however when I put the default filter of '*.*' it reacts to the temporary files created with this saving. I don't want that though, as there are more files in this folder that the watcher should not react to. How do I fix this filter/watcher?

**EDIT**:
I just wanted to add some output to this question. Adding the line: `Write-Host $logline` after creating $logline I get the following ouput:

```
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
1      7dd34e5a-484...                 NotStarted    False                                 $path = $Event.Source...
2      d7a74a71-5ae...                 NotStarted    False                                 $path = $Event.Source...
```

Then I open the Excel File:

```
03/12/2024 11:34:39, Created, D:\Projects\test\~$test.xlsx
03/12/2024 11:34:40, Changed, D:\Projects\test\~$test.xlsx
```

Then I change and save the Excel file:

```
03/12/2024 11:35:06, Created, D:\Projects\test\845C7B30
03/12/2024 11:35:06, Changed, D:\Projects\test\845C7B30
03/12/2024 11:35:06, Changed, D:\Projects\test\845C7B30
```

Finally I close the excel file, but I get no further messages.

Comment: Is excel closed after the save? When excel opens a file, it gets a file lock. Saving may be picked up by your watcher, but it may not be able to access the file as its still locked by excel.

Comment: I have just added and edit that should help answer this question. I do open and close Excel, make edits, etc. But it never seems to trigger on the actual xlsx file, only on temp files. 

It does react to changes made to a .txt file when changed in notepad.

Comment: Just found the answer as it is registered as a "renamed" event, rather than a "changed" event. I have answered my own question below.

Answer (score 0):

The event was not triggered because Excel saving is registered as a "Renamed" event. So adding the line `Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action` with the other action registers gives the following output on a save in Excel:

```
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
6      bc4f7a5b-747...                 NotStarted    False                                 $path = $Event.Source...
7      a3977062-fbb...                 NotStarted    False                                 $path = $Event.Source...
8      f28260d1-43a...                 NotStarted    False                                 $path = $Event.Source...
03/12/2024 11:50:04, Created, D:\Projects\test\3B0A8B30
03/12/2024 11:50:04, Created, D:\Projects\test\3B0A8B30
03/12/2024 11:50:04, Changed, D:\Projects\test\3B0A8B30
03/12/2024 11:50:04, Changed, D:\Projects\test\3B0A8B30
03/12/2024 11:50:04, Changed, D:\Projects\test\3B0A8B30
03/12/2024 11:50:05, Changed, D:\Projects\test\3B0A8B30
03/12/2024 11:50:05, Renamed, D:\Projects\test\69E4C836.tmp
03/12/2024 11:50:05, Renamed, D:\Projects\test\69E4C836.tmp
03/12/2024 11:50:05, Renamed, D:\Projects\test\test.xlsx
03/12/2024 11:50:06, Renamed, D:\Projects\test\test.xlsx
```